# Non-exhaustive patterns in lambda error

Tags: haskell

After implementing a simple parser in Haskell, I ran the following example code to test my parer.

```
example = fst $ (\(Just x)->x) $ parse (tokenize "assign x := not(and(true, false)); print x; assign a := not(and(x, x)); print a; end;") :: Stmt
```

and it returns **Exception: Parse.hs:93:18-29: Non-exhaustive patterns in lambda**

What am I doing wrong here that might be the cause of this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're ending up feeding `Nothing` into the lambda `(\(Just x) -> x)`, causing a non-exhaustive pattern match error.  Instead, use the `maybe` function:

```
default_value :: Stmt
default_value = ???

maybe default_value fst $ parse (tokenize "...") :: Stmt
```

Comment: If I know that the string I am parsing shouldn't return an error, does that mean somewhere I implemented the parser wrong?

Comment: @user3277633 That's the only assumption I can make.  That's the only pattern you have in the code you've shown, if that's where the error is occurring then you're getting `Nothing` out of your parser.

Answer (score 2):

In your lambda `(\(Just x)->x)` you need to account for the possibility that its argument may be `Nothing`.

Try this:

```
hdlr (Just x) = x
hdlr Nothing = error "Failed"

example = fst $ hdlr $ parse (tokenize "assign x := not(and(true, false)); print x; assign a := not(and(x, x)); print a; end;") :: Stmt
```

Comment: If I know that the string I am parsing shouldn't return an error, does that mean somewhere I implemented the parser wrong?

Comment: Yes you're passing Nothing into the lambda,  try with the code I put above and you'll see pretty quickly if you get the "Failed" error or not